# Building a XOR gate on 3 inputs using only 5 AND/OR/NOT gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, computer-architecture

I would like to implement a `XOR` gate which takes a 3-bit input (in other words, the modulo-2 sum of the input bits) **using only 5** `OR` **and** `AND` **gates**. As this is a pure thought experiment, any number of inverters can be used.

Is this even possible? After crawling the web for a long time, the only solution I come up with is chaining two 3-gates `XOR`, which yields a sum of 6 gates.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: If any number of inverters can be used, then yes. 4x 3-input AND gates and 1x 4-input OR gate. And that is directly from a Karnaugh map with no reduction/simplification.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Tom Carpenter's comment

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4PiyO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
where the 3 OR gates can be combined into a single 4-input OR gate (sorry, but the editor only provides 2 and 3 input gates).

It's not necessary to generate a Karnaugh map for this function. The output will be high if all 3 inputs are high (AND 1) or 1 input is high while the other 2 are low (AND 2,3,4).

Answer (score 0):

Using just 2-port OR and NAND:

```
t1 = OR(b, c)
t2 = NAND(b, c)
t3 = NAND(t1, t2)
t4 = NAND(a, t3)
t5 = OR(a, t3)
t6 = NAND(t4, t5)
```

where result is in t6.

```
| a | b | c | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | t6 |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 1 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 | 
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

I see you want just 5 gates. I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: I should have made clear that in my model of computation, I count multiple input gates as single elements (just like the 4-input `OR` gate used in the solution). Thank you for your help anyway.